# How to show eras in DateFormat?

Tags: date, dart, date-format, dart-intl

I'm not looking for something powerful, for date format `DateFormat` is enough but i need to add `A.D` or `B.C` like in Anno Domini for dates.

Now i know it's not even a challenge to  customize it but I'm looking for best way to do it with the official API so it can adapt to changes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`package:intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)'s [`DateFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class should be able to do with the `G` formatter:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var date = DateTime(2021, 5, 6);
  print(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd G').format(date)); // Prints: 2021-05-06 AD
}
```

Note that negative years seem to be directly assumed to be BC; that is, a year of -1 seems to be treated as 1 BC.  [This might not be what you expect if you want year 0 to be invalid](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/401).

Comment: It should be a problem but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero  "Historians have never included a year zero." so if the system wasn't abused it won't be a problem

Comment: @OverLoadedBurden Well, if you try to compute durations (e.g. by subtracting a BC year from an AD year), then your duration will be off by 1 year.

Comment: you are right, but the system cares for original making date of old artifacts. so, am on the safe side.